# Adipoli jQuery Image Hover Plugin - Run animations on hover of other elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Does anyone know if you can use Adipolo to hover over a different element for the image animations to take effect?

At the moment I am using:-

```
             $('#img-caption-one').adipoli({
                  'startEffect' : 'grayscale',
                  'hoverEffect' : 'foldLeft'
             });
```

I have tried the following but this just stops the image hover plugin from working:

```
      $('#element').mouseenter(function() {

             $('#img-caption-one').adipoli({
                  'startEffect' : 'grayscale',
                  'hoverEffect' : 'foldLeft'
             }); 

      }),
```

This is the plugin:  (http://cube3x.com/adipoli-jquery-image-hover-plugin/)

Doesn't seem to be much information in the help documents.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
$('#img-caption-one').adipoli({
    'startEffect' : 'grayscale',
    'hoverEffect' : 'foldLeft'
});

$('#element').mouseenter(function(){
    $('#img-caption-one').trigger('mouseenter');
})
```